# How to check if a number is an integer in .NET?

Tags: .net, isinteger

Say I've got a string which contains a number. I want to check if this number is an integer.

#### Examples

```
IsInteger("sss") => false 

IsInteger("123") => true

IsInterger("123.45") =>false
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use int.[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). It will return a bool if it can parse the string and set your out parameter to the value

```
 int val;
if(int.TryParse(inputString, out val))
{
    //dosomething
}
```

Comment: That answer above is only correct if the number will always be -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If it is larger you will need long.TryParse(). EG: a 16 digit credit card number...

Answer (score 5):

There are two immediate options that you can use.

**Option 1** - *preferred* - use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx).

```
int res;
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse("sss", out res));
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse("123", out res));
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse("123.45", out res));
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse("123a", out res));
```

This outputs:

```
False
True
False
False
```

**Option 2** - use regular expressions

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("^-?[0-9]+$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Match("sss").Success);
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Match("123").Success);
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Match("123.45").Success);
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Match("123a").Success);
```

This outputs:

```
False
True
False
False
```

Comment: Hi, gave a vote for supplementing with regex. Its something i dont think of using enough in my daily work. Thanks.

Comment: The examples are very useful.  Especially to show that `int.TryParse` returns false for a decimal value.  I was wondering if it might return true because the input value was numeric and truncate it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) and do something like this...

```
string str = "10";
int number = 0;
if (int.TryParse(str, out number))
{
    // True
}
else
{
    // False
}
```